# subprocess open under osx

Tags: python, macos, subprocess

I have a line in my prog which I use to launch additional instances of my program:

```
a=subprocess.Popen(__file__)
```

and under linux it works ok.

But under osx, it doesnt create a new window as it should (the program is a Tkinter program), yet it doesnt give any error at all.
(and I checked that **_*file*_** is in fact the correct name of the running program, wich is executable)

The return is this:

```
>    pprint (vars(a))
{'_child_created': True,
 'pid': 38865,
 'returncode': None,
 'stderr': None,
 'stdin': None,
 'stdout': None,
 'universal_newlines': False}
```

any hints?

Comment: to start with the same python executable and to pass the same command-line arguments: `p = Popen([sys.executable] + sys.argv)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an embarrassing problem there. You know what ? Your window is simply hidden behind the other one created earlier.

To see that, make the latest created window to be shown in front of the first one as in:

```
import Tkinter
import subprocess

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        open('bluh_check')
    except IOError:
        open('bluh_check', 'w').close()
        x = subprocess.Popen(['python', __file__])
        print vars(x)
        title = 'there'
    else:
        title = 'hi'

    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    root.title(title)
    root.withdraw()
    root.deiconify()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: it was even more embarassing: my prog silently exits if called without an argument, and I just provided **__file__** to it. I found the best solution is to call it simply as **a=subprocess.Popen(sys.argv)**: the 0th list value is the program name, all the rest its command line arguments